# Verschachtelte erweiterte Partizipialkonstruktion -- gibt es so etwas?

Tags: grammar, participle

Im Deutschen kann ein und dieselbe Information sowohl mit einem oder mehreren Relativsätzen als auch mit einer erweiterten Partizipialkonstruktion ausgedrückt werden.

> Der Vater, der die Mutter begrüßt, die das Kind im Arm hält, lächelt.
>
> Der die das Kind im Arm haltende Mutter begrüßende Vater lächelt.

Letzteres klingt verquer, ist aber regelgerecht, oder?

Gibt es Beispiele in der Literatur -- Sachbücher, Romane, journalistische Arbeiten -- für eine solche Konstruktion?

Comment: Ein solcher Satz ist meiner Meinung nach kaum oder nur schwer zu lesen und wird mit hoher Wahrscheinlichkeit vermieden. [Dennoch kannst du sowas ähnliches finden](http://books.google.de/books?id=7EIx7__KuxoC&pg=PA42&dq=%22der+die+die%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=3Of7UNH-Jo_bsgb6w4DwAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22der%20die%20die%22&f=false), wobei ersteres synonym zu "welcher, welches, welche" ist.

Comment: Gutes Beispiel, danke. Sehr clever, nach "der die die" zu suchen... mein Versuch mit "der die das" war zum Scheitern verurteilt :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Klar gibt es solche, den Leser wollknäuelartig in Gedankenflüge verstrickende und sich dadurch stilistisch auf schlüpfrigem Boden bewegende Auswüchse grammatikalisch zwar korrekter aber verschachtelter Schreibweisen zur Verschleierung ansonsten klarer aber nun den Leser in spannenden Bögen umschweifender Sachverhalte.

Ein Beispiel aus jüngerer Zeit aus einem Artikel der Schwäbischen Zeitung:

> Einen erdigen rauen Blues legten sie vor, daneben Rocksongs, die in ihrer hymnischen Monumentalität eines „Watching the Egyptians“ an die irren, nie enden wollenden und sich immer noch steigern könnenden höhenflugverdächtigen Gitarrensoli einstiger Rockbandkracher erinnern. <sup>[Babette Caesar, Schwäbische Zeitung 30.12.2012](http://www.schwaebische.de/region/allgaeu/leutkirch/stadtnachrichten-leutkirch_artikel,-Satter-Blues-und-knackige-Rocksongs-_arid,5370734.html)</sup>

Comment: Takkat! Das ist waffenscheinpflichtiges Deutsch :)  +1